# Javascript, Underscore trying to return the key of an object with the highest value

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter, underscore.js

I have an object

```
obj = { "13-17": { "total_fans": 5 }, 
        "18-24": { "total_fans": 10 }, 
        "25-34": { "total_fans": 15 } 
      }
```

and I want to return from `obj` the key of the object with the highest `total_fans`, so in this case it would be `25-34`

Comment: Loop and compare? Try `for..in`

Comment: Cool, good luck with that! If you have a specific question, feel free to ask. Make sure you included your attempts to solve the problem. Next time, you don't need to tell us beforehand what you are doing, just tell us when you ask a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about combining _.keys and _.max ?

```
_.max(_.keys(obj), function(key){ 
  return obj[key]["total_fans"]; 
});
```

This will return "25-34"

And be careful with the empty object ({}), it will return -Infinity... do a test with _.isEmpty(obj) before!